# Using Regex to help clean CSS values

Tags: css, regex, pattern-matching

I'm hoping regex can help me locate inefficiently written values in CSS. Some older developers, for example, would write margin values as *margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px*, which I'd like to rewrite in shorthand as *margin: 5px*. Obviously the number values (as well as the unit values: px, em, %, etc) can (and do) vary but I'd need to devise a way of looking for repeating numbers that all match each other.

Is this possible? My knowledge of regex is, regrettably, extremely limited. Can any kind soul give me some pointers on how I would achieve this pattern matching?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "back references"
An example of regexp :

```
/(padding|margin)[:] ([0-9](px|em)) \2 \2 \2;/
```

[Test here](http://regex101.com/r/xO1wG2/1)

in PHP you could do something like this :

```
$your_css = preg_replace('@(padding|margin)[:] ([0-9]+(px|em))\s\2\s\2\s\2\s?;@ui,'\1:\2;', $your_css);
```

Comment: Thanks Sly, that's really been a help.

Comment: you're welcome. Curious to see the final result ;)

Answer (score 1):

Search for: `((?:padding|margin)\s*:)(\s+\d+(?:px|em|%){4};?` and replace it with `$1$2`.

**Perl:**

```
$css =~ s/((?:padding|margin)\s*:)(\s+\d+(?:px|em|%){4};?/$1$2/g;
```

**php:**

```
$css = preg_replace('/((?:padding|margin)\s*:)(\s+\d+(?:px|em|%){4};?/', "$1$2", $css);
```

You may add other units:

```
(?:px|em|cm|mm|in|pt|pc|%)
```